# Is there Seebeck effect on junction between same metal but with different isotopes?

Tags: spectroscopy, thermoelectricity

I recently discovered [Mössbauer spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_spectroscopy) and its explanation drove me to think we should observe the [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect) between two similar metals but with different isotopes.

The main reason that drove me to think that is because the weight of each isotope is different and the thermal activity could eject an electron easier from the lighter kernel.

I'd like to do the experiment but I do not know where to find 2 samples of same the metal with different isotopes, and I was unable to find in books the answer to that question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Seebeck coefficient of metals is due to difference in the electronic densities of states at the Fermi level. Any isotope effect would be very very small.

But to find samples, you could look at how people measured isotope effects in superconductivity (where atomic mass *is* important in the BCS theory).